# Very slow MongoDB count in big database

Tags: python, mongodb, count, pymongo

I have a database with a collection in it with a large amount of documents (several millions).
In this database I have (amongst others) the fields _VIOLATIONTYPE (int) and _DURATION (int).
Now I would like to count the amount of documents that have a _VIOLATIONTYPE of 15 or less and a _DURATION of 10 or less.
To do this I execute the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymongo
import timeit


client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
database = client['bgp_route_leaks']

collection = database['valleys']

collection.ensure_index('_VIOLATIONTYPE', unique=False)
collection.ensure_index('_DURATION', unique=False)

start = timeit.default_timer()

cursor = collection.find({'$and': [{'_VIOLATIONTYPE': {'$lt': 16}}, {'_DURATION': {'$lt': 10}}]}, {'_DURATION': 1, '_id': 0})

print('Explain: {}'.format(cursor.explain()))
print('Count: {}'.format(cursor.count()))
print('Time: {}'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start))
```

This prints out:

```
Explain: {u'nYields': 4, u'nscannedAllPlans': 6244545, u'allPlans': [{u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor _VIOLATIONTYPE_1', u'indexBounds': {u'_VIOLATIONTYPE': [[-1.7976931348623157e+308, 16]]}, u'nscannedObjects': 124, u'nscanned': 124, u'n': 34}, {u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor _DURATION_1', u'indexBounds': {u'_DURATION': [[-1.7976931348623157e+308, 10]]}, u'nscannedObjects': 6244298, u'nscanned': 6244298, u'n': 5678070}, {u'cursor': u'BasicCursor', u'indexBounds': {}, u'nscannedObjects': 123, u'nscanned': 123, u'n': 36}], u'millis': 30815, u'nChunkSkips': 0, u'server': u'area51:27017', u'n': 5678107, u'cursor': u'BtreeCursor _DURATION_1', u'scanAndOrder': False, u'indexBounds': {u'_DURATION': [[-1.7976931348623157e+308, 10]]}, u'nscannedObjectsAllPlans': 6244545, u'isMultiKey': False, u'indexOnly': True, u'nscanned': 6244298, u'nscannedObjects': 6244298}
Count: 5678107
Time: 52.4030768871
```

While running this I also executed db.currentOp() in another window, which returned

```
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "opid" : 15,
                        "active" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 4,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "bgp_route_leaks.valleys",
                        "query" : {
                                "$query" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "_VIOLATIONTYPE" : {
                                                                "$lt" : 16
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "_DURATION" : {
                                                                "$lt" : 10
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "$explain" : true
                        },
                        "client" : "127.0.0.1:46819",
                        "desc" : "conn1",
                        "threadId" : "0x7fd69b31c700",
                        "connectionId" : 1,
                        "locks" : {
                                "^" : "r",
                                "^bgp_route_leaks" : "R"
                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "numYields" : 5,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(8816104),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                                },
                                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                        "r" : NumberLong(4408723),
                                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Now I have read that the most common source for slow MongoDB queries is missing indexes.
However, I have ensured indexes for both _VIOLATIONTYPE and _DURATION and the explain tells me u'indexOnly': True.
I also read that a NUMA architecture could slow things down and that I should start the service via the command

```
sudo numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
(/proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode is already set to 0)
```

which I know have done, but it still takes about a minute for this count and even longer for others, so I was wondering what to do to make the query faster.

Running

```
db.runCommand({compact: 'bgp_route_leaks'})
```

in the mongo shell has also been tried with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to get the counts much faster?

The MongoDB version is 2.4.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your `explain` output you will see that the query that was using `_VIOLATIONTYPE` is scanning only 124 objects and the the query using `_DURATION` is scanning 6244545 objects.

Although MongoDB 2.6+ can use [index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/), compound index will always be faster.

You need to create a compound index on those fields:

```
collection.create_index([("_VIOLATIONTYPE", ASCENDING),("_DURATION", ASCENDING)]);
```

**EDIT**

In versions 2.4 MongoDB performance was significantly improved ([JIRA-1752](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752)).

Also, it's worth noticing that `explain` command is displaying details for a query not count command.

Unfortunately, you can't use `explain` on a `count` command, but there is a [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3493) opened for that issue.

To measure the performance of only the `count` command you should probably remove `explain` from your test. Also, you need to repeat the query multiple times (100x, 1000x...) and take an average to get an correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it certainly improved the performance (after initializing the keys for several minutes), but not as much as I had hoped for. It now outputs the following Time: 22.7881669998. Do you know of any other ways to improve the speed further? Because I need to perform multiple similar queries and currently it takes almost an hour for them to finish.

Comment: @user3664397 - what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: The MongoDB version is 2.4.9, I have now added it to the original post

Comment: @user3664397 - added a possible explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks again, but using that find query will increase the Time to 240.429248095

Comment: @user3664397 - removed that part then. Also, it's worth noticing that you're actually measuring the speed of the query by using `explain` and not the speed of count operation. You're basically executing the query twice.

Comment: I noticed that indeed, however, half the time is still too much for most of the queries. And getting a more accurate performance value is also not that interesting since it is mostly around that value and I need it to be significantly faster. I have found that the cause of the problem is likely that the indexed values do not fit in the RAM memory and that most of it is stored in swap memory. So I think the best solution would be to just decrease the amount of records to be handled. Not sure how I am going to approach it in my situation yet though. Thanks for all the suggestions though. :)

Comment: @user3664397 - you should always check that you have enough resources when performance is an issue :)

Comment: @user3664397 - so did you try just to 'count()' on collection (instead of 'finding' and checking cursor elements)?
how does it compare to your version?

Comment: @ChristianP Yeah it seems so, I'll accept this answer as it did help improve the speed, and I will check if I can redesign the database to be more memory efficient. [at]Volodymyr Metlyakov: In PyMongo collection.count takes no arguments, it only counts the amount of elements in the collection, it cannot count elements that meet a certain condition.